# How can i add an event to JSpinner if its value has been increased in GUI?

Tags: java, events, jspinner

I use GUI and I want to add an event in my jSpinner if its value has been increased, i tried all events in the proprieties for example mouseClicked(MouseEvent) but no one of them works, How can i add this event?

```
private void Points1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    //Points1 is a JSpinner
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for rating this question.");
}
```

Also i want to control the jSpinner's values, it must start with 0 and increase to infirmity but never goes to negative numbers. how can i do this?

Comment: [How to use Spinners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)

Comment: Is there something wrong with the stateChanged() event??

Comment: As for Start value, Minimum value, and Maximum value, you willl need to enter into the model property. and make the necessary changes there. As for a max of infinity....forget about it. Infinity is an awefully large number...lol

Comment: yes it doesn't work.. of course it will never go to infinity :))